# How to correct Spring MVC RequestMapping order?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have an existing Spring MVC service running with the following RequestMapping.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "{user}/**", method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

I now need to add a new method to the same controller with the following RequestMapping.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "api/{user}/**", method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

When I test against the new URL, Spring is always choosing the first function so that this
second function is inaccessible.

Is there anyway that I can get Spring to use my new "api" method? The only option I can think of is to create a new Java servlet in my web.xml, but I'd like to do something simpler. I did try making two different controllers, with `@Controller` and `@Controller("api")`, but that did not solve the problem.

Comment: Do changing the order of method definitions help?

Comment: I would not expect it to matter, but I did just try it and it made no difference.

Comment: The controllers I use start the @RequestMapping value with a "/". So I would expect to see @RequestMapping(value = "/api...

Comment: @user636334, I was excited about the possibilities with that possible solution, but it did not make any difference.

Comment: Is `{user}` a string variable by any chance?

Comment: @kdgregory, Yes {user} is a string.

Comment: The decision what handler is used is coded in `org.springframework.util.AntPathMatcher.AntPatternComparator.compare(String, String)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that your parameter for `user` is `String`, Spring is assuming that you've been invoked for user `api`.

There are a couple of ways to solve this. The first (and best) is to make your request mappings more narrow: fully specify the mapping, rather than relying on "`**`" at the end.

The second approach is to disallow an "api" user, using a [regex](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.2.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-ann-requestmapping-uri-templates-regex) in your mapping. Something like the following should work:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "{user:[^a][^p][^i]}/**", method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

Comment: We need the ** at the end because the number of path parts is variable. I tried a variation of your suggestion which is working well. `{user:^(?!api).*}/**`